# Remote js file works from a directory but not a subdirectory?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

I'm just learning `javascript`, making an external radio player for other website owners to embed.

I'm including `.js` files in my head from a subdirectory `/scripts/externalplayer` on my top-level domain, which doesn't work.

Putting `/externalplayer` on the root of the domain and calling it from there works just fine. Is there a specific way of linking `js` from a remote `URL` that's not obvious?

*Note:* Including a `.css` file from the subdirectory worked fine.

```
<script src="http://example.com/externalplayer/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://example.com/externalplayer/mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What do you mean not  obvious?

Comment: By that I mean not in any basic javascript guides. Excuse me